# ES: what should be optimum index.max_result_window?

Tags: elasticsearch

In `elasticsearch`, there is setting called `index.max_result_window` which defines max possible documents in one batch of `scroll` api result. Its default value is 10000. But my search result has more than 10000 documents and it takes around a min to perform the ES query so I am interested in increasing this setting value. I want to know how does this setting affect performance of responses?

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings):

> `index.max_result_window`
>
> The maximum value of `from` + `size` for searches to this index. Defaults to `10000`. Search requests **take heap memory and time proportional to `from` + `size` and this limits that memory**.

So it will take considerably longer if you push out more data at once.

Comment: does that mean I should reduce `index.max_result_window` to increase performance?

Comment: Yes and no. In the first place, you should optimize your query. Unless it is some kind of indexing, your query time is really high.
Yes - because if it is not indexing (or some related stuff) and you want to display information, go with a smaller window. `scroll`pagination will handle the rest. You don't need to display all 10k hits at once, right?
No - if you want to be able to client-side search or sort through results (e.g. with JS or browser search) you will want to have all results first.